# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

In T-SQL I'm attempting to update a stock user field with the number of weeks we expect it to be delivered to us by taking the difference between today and the purchase order due in dates. However the select query can return more than one line of purchase orders if there is more than one purchase order containing that product (obviously). I would like to take the smallest number it returns / minimum value but obviously cannot do this within the update query. Can anyone recommend a workaround? Thanks.

```
UPDATE [Exchequer].[ASAP01].[STOCK]
SET stUserField7 = DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112),min(tlLineDate)) / 7 + 1
FROM [Exchequer].[ASAP01].[STOCK]
JOIN [Exchequer].[ASAP01].[CUSTSUPP]
ON stSupplier = acCode
JOIN [Exchequer].[ASAP01].[DETAILS]
ON stCode = tlStockCodeTrans1
WHERE stSupplier <> '' AND stQtyOnOrder > '0' AND stQtyOnOrder > stQtyAllocated 
AND tlOurRef like 'POR%' AND (floor(tlQtyDel) + floor(tlQtyWOFF)) < floor(tlQty) 
AND tlLineDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(), 112)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a `SELECT` query with columns for the following:

1. The primary key of the `[Exchequer].[ASAP01].[STOCK]` table
2. The new desired `stUserField7`

Given the `MIN(tlLineDate)` expression in the original question, if this `SELECT` query does not have either a `GROUP BY` clause or change to use an `APPLY` instead of a `JOIN`, you've probably done something wrong.

Once you have that query, use it in an `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.stUserField7 = t.NewValueFromSelectQuery
FROM [Exchequer].[ASAP01].[STOCK] s
INNER JOIN (
    --- your new SELECT query here
) t ON t.<primary key field(s)> = s.<primary key field(s)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you casting date to varchar for the difference?

This is not date but how you can use a window function in an update

```
declare @maps table(name varchar(10), isUsed bit, code varchar(10));
insert into @Maps values 
       ('NY', 1, 'NY1')
     , ('NY', 0, 'NY2')
     , ('FL', 0, 'FL1')
     , ('TX', 0, 'TX1')
declare @Results table (id int identity primary key, Name varchar(20), Value int, Code varchar(20), cnt int)
insert into @results values
       ('FL', 12, 'FL1', null)
     , ('TX', 54, 'TX1', null)
     , ('TX', 56, 'TX1', null)
     , ('CA', 50, 'CA1', null)
     , ('NJ', 40, 'NJ1', null)

select * from @results 
order by name, Value desc

update r
set r.cnt = tt.cnt
from @results r 
join ( select id, max(value) over (partition by name) as cnt
       from @Results 
     ) tt 
on r.id = tt.id

select * from @results 
order by name, value desc
```